# Clear angular toastr only if not self clearing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using [angular toastr](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr) in an app.

I have set up so that by default, toastr messages do not have a timeout. The user must clear the toastr message. However, when the user moves on to another page, the toastr message is cleared, like so...

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function() {    
            //clear any toastrs visible when navigating to a different route
            toastr.clear();
        });
```

I would like to adjust this code so that it only affects toastrs that have a timeout === 0.

The reason for this, is that when i add/edit a product, the user is sent automatically to a listing screen, and i would like to display a success toastr that does have a timeout. However currently that toastr will be cleared by this function so the message is not seen by the user.

Is there a way to acheive this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know that there is any built-in functionality to do what you want. However, a simple solution could be to create a ToastrQueueService that you would push notifications that should not be cleared. In the $locationChangeStart handler, you would then clear the toast as you do now, and AFTER that pop all toasts out of the queue and show them.